# Live reload/refresh for HTML/CSS & Javascript across 2 monitors?

Tags: real-time, multiple-monitors, live-update

Any help/advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

I'm looking for what I would consider a standard setup for modern day web design/development. Basically I have a dual monitor setup and I would like to code on one screen and have the changes displayed in real-time on the other screen.

Up until yesterday I was using jsbin in this way and it was working great. I had one browser setup with the coding stuff (HTML/CSS/jQuery) and I then had another separate browser open on the second monitor which updated instantly as I typed. So if I changed a CSS rule for example it was shown in real-time on the second monitor without me having to do ANYTHING. No saving, no refreshing, no switching tabs - NOTHING.

However, for whatever reason jsbin now refuses to update in real-time and it will only show the code changes if I manually refresh the browser. I've emailed jsbin about this but they can't diagnose the issue.

So what I'm looking for is either an online alternative, or a local alternative. However, everything (and I mean EVERYTHING) that I've tried so far can't do what jsbin did.

dabblet.com, jsFiddle.net, liveweave.com, codepen.io, cssdeck.com etc

But all of the above don't offer a second tab/browser that I can move to the second monitor to show the code updates in real-time which is the most important thing.

Surely there must be an easy solution to this? Is it not common to code in this way on 2 monitors whilst developing a website? I'd really appreciate any help on this.

Many thanks
Ben

Answer (score 2):

For local option, [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) has Live Preview mode.

After you open your project or file for editing, select File -> Live Preview

It launches a browser window, then your changes are reflected as you type, no save or browser refresh needed.

Comment: Brackets is a good suggestion. But unfortunately I can't get Live Preview to work using php includes; when you click on a php include file to edit it the browser loads just that file without any html/css context. Plus for some reason it occasionally stops live reloading. Seems like too much hassle to battle with it for now. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Liveweave](http://liveweave.com) with my dual monitor setup. I keep the HTML/CSS in my left window/monitor and the JS/Preview in my right monitor. Works great!

Comment: Sounds perfect! But I can't see an option in Liveweave to split the workspace across 2 monitors/browsers/tabs? I can adjust the layout using the layout buttons in the Liveweave toolbar, but it only applies the changes to a single browser/tab? How exactly did you manage it?

Comment: What I meant was to expand the window so that you have the preview on the right side and the code panels on the left side. But if you are looking to separate out the preview panel, this method will not work. That being said, what is the purpose of having the preview in a separate tab? I am just curious. Doesn't the above method do the same...just saying.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. I can see how that would work but it's not ideal as my monitors are different resolutions/ratios so the browser split across 2 monitors would mean some height cropping of the browser window. Thanks for the clever workaround though.

Comment: The reason I need a completely separate window is because I'm testing responsive/elastic layouts and I need to regularly resize the browser so it needs to be a standalone window. The method you suggested would just cause constant headaches because Liveweave needs its columns readjusting everytime the browser is resized. Thanks again though.

Comment: That makes sense. Not sure whether it helps, but just so you know, Liveweave has a built-in ruler for responsive design at the bottom of the screen. You can change the preview panel size to the required horizontal pixel size.

Comment: Great tip, thanks. I'll definitely keep that in mind for when I'm playing around with different layout ideas etc.